# No changes detected in app 'learning_logs'

Tags: python, django, terminal

I ran the code settings.py and went to INSTALLED APPS and added learning_logs:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'learning_logs',
```

Then in the terminal I ran 'python manage.py makemigrations learning_logs'

However it results in 'No changes detected in app 'learning_logs'

Note that I read some other articles and got no good answer

Also note that the end bracket is supposed to be in the dictionary

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

1. Add `__init__.py` file into the app folder.
2. Make sure you have some models classes created in models.py file in the app

Answer (score 0):

Please check your model definition and make sure that it inherits from django `models.Model`!

```py
from django.db import models


class MyCustomModel(models.Model):
    ...
```